# How to convert or skip null date time?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

How can I convert or skip the `null` date time, my date time was from database
the code I use was

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{ 
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {

            if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i) == null)
            {
                break;
            }
             DateTime  sg = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]);
             if (!repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Contains(sg))
                {
                    repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(sg);
                }
        }
}
```

when i try to run the program and because in database of date got null type it give me error :

> object cannot be cast from DBNULL to other types. at
>   system.dbnull.system.iconvertible.toDatetime(IformatProvider provider)

Answer (score 0):

Using `DBNull.Value`:

```
DateTime? sg = null;
if(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"] != DBNull.Value)
   sg = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]);

if (sg != null && !repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Contains(sg))
{
   repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(sg);
}
```

Comment: would you mind see the code again ?, i cant put the variable of sg inside another if

Comment: your code works, but do you have any idea how to convert date null value to null ?, because when i try to call the null value it give me error

Comment: @DavidChopperField Check the edited answer. you can use `sg.HasValue` or `sg == null` to check if sg is *NULL* in any code that follows.

Comment: iam sorry i dont quite understand. i am just declaring `datetime? = null` it didnt give me anything.. did you mean that i have to put another `if` to check if gridview1.getdatarow was null  then convert it?..

Comment: @DavidChopperField We're already doing that in the above if statement. What are you trying to do other than the code above when the date is null in the grid. Please be specific and clear.

Comment: sory, althought its clear. i just want to ask how can i convert null datetime value. from code above was just skipping the DBnull value. i did some experiment `if(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"] == DBNull.Value)
{sg = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]);` it give me error. i cant getting the null value in sg

Comment: i am already try that. but the error was `value cannot be null. parameter name : value` what went wrong

Comment: @DavidChopperField Do you want to add *NULL* to `repositoryItemComboBox1` ?? That is not valid or logical.

Comment: yep, well thats explains it. also is it because of my datase type `not null` too ?

Comment: @DavidChopperField The default selected value for `repositoryItemComboBox1` is *NULL* and you can specifiy a *NULL-Text* for it like *Value not Selected* or *Please Select a Value*. Why do you exactly need to add *NULL* to your selection control ?

Comment: well,i know in column filter itself already got blank. but in my repositoryitemcombobox i make it like dropdown. if i dont use `if DBNull.Value` i cant just put in repository itemcombobox, the error was same `value cannot be null` but with your solution it work and skip the null value. so iam curios how about to put null value it self. and column `date` itself was a `datetime` which contain date and time.

Comment: @DavidChopperField `DateTime?` type can be *NULL*

Comment: but it will put the same error as the original thread.when iam just directly convert it `DateTime  signout = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["signOut"]);` i'll just the first solution though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your `gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]` is `DBNull` or not before that like;

```
DateTime sg;
if(!(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"] is DBNull))
{
   sg = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]);
}
```

Comment: well, it works, i cant use `sg` inside if repository item, iam edited a piece of code

Comment: @DavidChopperField Then you can declare your variable outside of this if block. Updated my answer.

Comment: your code works!
can i ask other question ?
the code you give me were skipping the date null value.. how do i call or store a null date? (convert date null value to null) i cant find any answer on stack.